# Fail to assign a cv::Mat object in C++ class

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my code to define a class and input some doubles so that the member function can give a Mat object.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class A{
    public:
        void fun(double, double, double);
        void printfun();

    private:
        Mat R;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    A a;
    a.fun(0.05, 0.05, 0.5);
    a.printfun();

    return 0;
}

void A::fun(double R_x, double R_y, double R_theta){
    R = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << R_x,0,0,0,R_y,0,0,R_theta);
    #double R_init[3][3]={{R_x, 0,   0}, 
    #                    {0,   R_y, 0}, 
    #                    {0,   0,   R_theta*3.1415/180}};
    #    
    #R = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, R_init);

    cout << R << endl;

}

void A::printfun(){
    cout << R << endl;
}
```

In the function `A::fun`, I need to compute a `Mat` object **R** which is defined as a private variable. However, when I use the first sentence in fun to do that, both the `cout` in `fun()` and `printfun()` give the right matrix. If I use the method in gray, the `cout` in `fun()` prints right but the `cout` in `printfun()` gives a wrong matrix R.

That is kind of weird because it seems when the `fun()` returns, matrix R computed by the second method changes somehow. If this method is not used in class type, it functions right and gives a correct matrix R.

The other question is nothing related to this problem. If I could always defines a variable(say, R) in public or in private and then use a member function to assign a value to this variable, then the return type of member function could always be "void" rather than the type of the variable it assigns. Is this the way the c++ class type functions?

I am new to c++ so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple explanation for the behavior you are observing.

> it seems when the fun() returns, matrix R computed by the second
>   method changes somehow

Your observation is correct. Following is the difference between the first and second assignment:

In the first method, the memory for the contents of `R` is allocated dynamically and then initialized with the specified values. When the function `fun` returns, the contents of `R` are preserved due to dynamic allocation.

In the second method, a static array `R_init` (which is local to the function `fun`) is initialized with the specified values. Then in the next line, `R` is created and set to use the contents of `R_init`. The key difference here is that no dynamic memory allocation happens. `R` just uses the already allocated array `R_init` for storing the values. It means if we modify `R_init`, the contents of `R` will also change. When `fun` returns, there is no guarantee of validity of contents of `R_init` (a.k.a [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C.2B.2B)) which is resulting in garbage values being printed.

Although for static initialization, the first approach is preferred. But if you really want to use the second method, you can force a separate copy of the memory using the `Mat::clone` function like this:

```
R = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F, R_init).clone();
```

For the second question:

> Is this the way the c++ class type functions?

The function return type may not necessarily be `void` as it may be dependent on what kind of design patterns you are following. It can totally be a matter of choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer perfectly solved my problem.  I need to read carefully about shallow/deep copy in OpenCV.